# SQL - How to select values from two columns that pair only with each other?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table that looks like that:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 3 |
| b | 3 |

I want to select values from the `A` column that always have the same value in the `B` column - in that case, my output would be **"b"**

Bare in mind, I don't want to use values from the `B` column directly, I want to find out for which values from the `A` column there's only one value from the `B` column that matches.

I've tried

```sql
SELECT A, COUNT(DISTINCT B)
FROM Table
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B) = 1
```

...but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Your queries actually look correct, what is the current output?

Comment: _Doesn't seem to work_? What do you get, and what's wrong with it?

Comment: The query is correct. Can you add a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/btGcOH30) to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Are you perhaps selecting and grouping by more columns than just `A`  in your actual query?

Comment: If you have problems with null values in column  b maybe try `HAVING count(b) = count(*) and COUNT(DISTINCT b) = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Your current queries look to be either completely correct or at least on the right track.  Here are a couple of aggregation options:

```sql
SELECT A
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B) = 1;
```

and:

```sql
SELECT A
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY A
HAVING MIN(B) = MAX(B);
```

And we can also handle this using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT A
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourTable t2
    WHERE t2.A = t1.A AND t2.B <> t1.B
);
```